# how to make idea continue unit tests when one test failed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, testng

I am using testng to do some unit tests. When I run it on the idea of my local windows pc, one of these unit tests failed, and the subsequent unit tests were skipped. It shows like this:
[image]

My BackGroud:
Windows 11 22H2

java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)

TestNg 6.14.3

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.5080.55

I want it to continue running unitl all unit tests finish, so I can see how many unit tests have problems in total。

What should I do ?

Comment: As far as I know, the IDEA and Gradle would run all tests by default even if one failed. Do you have any annotation like `@Ignore` in the last test which ignores it? If you comment on the failed test, would the last test still ignore or not?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you are using Hard Asserts which stops the entire execution in the event of assertion failure. If you want to continue the execution irrespective of fail or pass, replace Assert statements with Soft Assertions wherever you expect a failure.